# Apple Push Notification Service Connection Idle Lifetime

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, http2, disconnection

I am working on implementing a provider for remote push notifications for IOS devices. I also read the following on the best practices guide on Apple's developer website

> Keep your connections with APNs open across multiple notifications;
>   don’t repeatedly open and close connections. APNs treats rapid
>   connection and disconnection as a denial-of-service attack. You should
>   leave a connection open unless you know it will be idle for an
>   extended period of time—for example, if you only send notifications to
>   your users once a day it is ok to use a new connection each day.

After implementing the logic for establishing the connection, I decided to test it out and left my server running for a bit. After coming back from dinner, I saw that my server had been disconnected by the apple push notification service. During the time my server was running, it was connected to the apple push notification service but idle. I read on another question that the service is not reliable and intermittently disconnects you. I was wondering if anyone had any idea of how long does the connection have to be idle for disconnecting you from the service and if anyone could suggest some best practices for dealing with the disconnection.

My main concern is that Apple will take rapid connection and disconnections as a DDOS attack. So I was intending to keep the connection opened as long as possible and just reconnect to the service when I get disconnected from it. Is this a common practice for dealing with APNS?

[UPDATE 4/5/2016]
I Implemented the reconnection logic but now appear to run to a problem that I do not understand about the service. According to Apple, they want us to keep the connection to the APN open across multiple notifications. However, after sending the first notification over the connection and seeing it display on my device, further notifications sent through the connection do not appear to go through. Can I only send one request per stream? Should I incrementally open streams as i send more requests?